# special character in file name is missing while using http post to upload a file onto server running python flask

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

example file name: `2^8.txt` 
my request:

```
var fileSelect = document.getElementById('myfile');
var files = fileSelect.files;
var formData = new FormData();
var file = files[0]; 
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
```

How i printed the file name using python flask:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return jsonify(status="fail")
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        print(filename)
```

I got `28.txt` instead of `2^8.txt`

I have tried using encodeURI(), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "^" character is being removed by the `secure_filename(file.filename)` function call, because werkzeug deems it unsafe (I'm not sure why but there will be a reason!).

Comment: Thank you. How could i not do a check on```secure_filename``` !